# Process logging binary data to log file

Tags: node.js, logging, upstart

I'm starting a node process with the following upstart script, logging stdout & stderr into separate files:

```
script
  sudo -u node /usr/local/bin/node /var/node/services/someServer.js 1> /var/log/node/someServer.log 2> /var/log/node/someServer.error.log
end script
```

The problem is that both log files have binary data in the head. I can't use less or more to quickly check those logs, which is terribly annoying. Any ideas how I can prevent that process logging binary data?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening using `less` with the `-f` and `-R` options.  `-f` will force open binary files and `-R` will better handle control characters, if they exist.  Does `cat` display the contents ok?